# Keep div open when a calendar is opened

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**Here is the jsfiddle**:

http://jsfiddle.net/93Fp2/3/

I've got a div called `divEtime` that should only appear when you hover over a the `li` item that is within the `ul`:

Here is the jquery for that:

```
$('#dEtime').hide();

            $(".eTime").hover(function () {
                $('#dEtime').fadeIn('slow');
            }, function () {
                $('#dEtime').fadeOut('slow');
            });
```

Here is the html showing the div as well as an `li` item that contains the class `eTime`

```
<ul id="ulPersonal">
      <li class="break eTime">
        <a href="http://someURL" title="t" target="_blank"><img src="./images/etime.png" alt="E-Time" /></a>
        <a href="http://someURL" title="t" target="_blank">t</a>
        <p>Manage</p>
        <div id="dEtime">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEtimeStart" runat="server" CssClass="datePickerDueDate" 
                         Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
           Some content
        </div>
      </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The issue is I also have a text box `txtEtimeStart` that uses jquery's date picker as such:

```
$(".datePickerDueDate").datepicker(
                    {
                        firstDay: 1,
                        constrainInput: false,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        selectOtherMonths: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
```

Notice in the html posted that the textbox has a class called `.datePickerDueDate`.  So my issue is when you open the date picker and move the mouse down to select a value for the textbox (which is in the div), the div fades out again.  It appears that when I go over the calendar control (the jquery date picker) that the hover over the div has lost focus causing the div to hide.

Is it possible to keep the div open while I am selecting a date from my calendar?  Otherwise what happens is the div hides but the calendar is still open.  I can still select a date but then I have to hover over the div again to see the value.

Comment: Provide live url or jsfiddle..

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93Fp2/3/  Hover over the li item in the jsfiddle, then click the input box, you will see a calendar display, but as soon as you pick a value the div hides again before you select a value...

Comment: do you really want the div to disappear onmouseout?

Comment: @iGanja - What would you recommend?  Otherwise the user is stuck closing it?

Comment: I was just asking what the desired behavior is. I believe there is a fix for this, but once the calendar closes, the div will also close. The only real difference will be that the div remains visible while the user selects a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just select the calendar's ID in your JQuery statement as well, and use `stop()`

http://jsfiddle.net/93Fp2/27/

```
$(".eTime, #ui-datepicker-div").hover(function () {
            $('#dEtime').stop().fadeIn('slow');
        }, function () {
            $('#dEtime').stop().fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: this one is better, but the hover behavior gets messed up after choosing a date.

Comment: This sort of works but there is some flickering when I move to select a date...+1 so far....but I'd still be interested if there would be no flickering.

Comment: IMO, it would be better if the input box just remained visible after the click or always, but yes, it will fadeOut whether you "un-hover" the calendar OR the input, as it is selected 'both.'  It isn't very friendly for UX, but it does what you asked I believe...

Comment: @RCNeil - Yes I think you are right the UX is not friendly.  I am going to keep it visible after "un hover".  I can always add a close link to show up.

Comment: +1 'cause I couldn't figure anything better ;) If the #ui-datepicker-div was actually placed within the #dEtime, this would be a no-brainer, but it isn't, and I'm not sure why.